# SQL in R: HAVING condition with only the condition of one row?

Tags: sql, r

I am learning to use SQL in R.
I want to select cities that are more northern than Berlin from a dataset.

For this, I have tried:

```
sql4 = "SELECT Name, Latitude FROM city HAVING Latitude > Latitude(Berlin)"

result4 = dbSendQuery(con, sql4)

df4 = dbFetch(result4)

head(df4)
```

and

```
sql4 = "SELECT Name, Latitude FROM city HAVING Latitude > (Name IN 'Berlin')"

result4 = dbSendQuery(con, sql4)

df4 = dbFetch(result4)

head(df4)
```

Neither syntax works unfortunatley.
So my question is: How do I select all cities "north from Berlin", i.e. latitude value higher than that of the Name row 'Berlin'? Is there a different, better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Berlin occur at most once in the `city` table, you may use:

```sql
SELECT Name, Latitude
FROM city
WHERE Latitude > (SELECT Latitude FROM city WHERE Name = 'Berlin');
```

You want to be using `WHERE` here to filter, rather than `HAVING`.  `HAVING` is for filtering aggregates when using `GROUP BY`, which you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually use Latitude(Berlin), I think. I typically use something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Latitude FROM city WHERE Latitude = (SELECT Latitude from city WHERE Name = "Berlin")
```

Hope this helps.
-Suhas